# Http Response inside a service in Android

Tags: android, service, android-activity, httpresponse

Hi I have a service in Android that handles the HTTP method POST as specified below. Now, I need to call an Intent in

> replaceResourceSegment()

method. It has a handler that takes nearly 90 seconds to complete the task. Within that time, control exits the handler block. But I want my program to continue within handler for POST.  In short, I want my service to pause for sometime inside the POST handler, till my Intent (with handler) completes its execution and I need to delay sending the response of HTTP Post.  Can some one guide me how to do this implementation?

```
    if(method.equals("POST"))
        {   
        conn.receiveRequestEntity((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request);             
        HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request).getEntity();          
        String content_type = ""+entity.getContentType();
        JSONReceived = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        if(content_type.contains("json"))
        {       
        Log.d(TAG,"Content received is: "+JSONReceived);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+constants.UPDATED_SCRIPT_FILE)));
        bufferedWriter.write(JSONReceived);
        bufferedWriter.close();            
        try {
            parseJSON(JSONReceived);
            replaceResourceSegment(); //Call to an intent with startActivityForResult()
            continueExecution(); //Continue the execution from here                                             
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG,"IOException line 157");
        }
```

Code for sending response back:

```
        HttpResponse postResponse = new BasicHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, 200, "OK");
        postResponse.setEntity(new StringEntity("Got it"));
        conn.sendResponseHeader(postResponse);
        conn.sendResponseEntity(postResponse);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using a boolean variable with default value false. It will be checked periodically and keeps the control inside the POST method's handler.

```
android.os.SystemClock.sleep(30000); //Sleeps for 30 seconds and invoke busy waiting in a thread
Thread syncThread = new Thread(new LoopCheck());
syncThread.start();
synchronized(syncThread)
{
Log.d(TAG,"Inside synchronized blockk");
try
{
syncThread.wait();
}catch(InterruptedException ie){
ie.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The thread class is defined as below:

```
class LoopCheck extends Thread{
public LoopCheck(){
}
public void run(){
while(true)
{
try {
Thread.sleep(10000);                    
if(write)
{                           
write = false;
synchronized(syncThread)
{
syncThread.notify();
}
break;
}                           
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}       
}
```